# Why does my Thermo Pride oil furnace need constant restarts?

Tags: heating, furnace

We have a Thermo Pride oil furnace that requires frequent restarts to run. We just purchased the house and had the annual service/safety check completed as it was neglected for several years. When the issue started two weeks ago it would run several days after being reset but today it will only run for about 5 minutes.

Any idea why the need for the constant re-starts/resets?

Answer (score 1):

Brand probably has nothing to do with it. You'll need a service call, and should already have made one (yes, you had it serviced - but it's not behaving correctly, so you need another one.)

Clogged nozzles are a common issue, but not the only one - bad or dirty flame sensors, bad high voltage ignitors, bad control systems are all possible issues. You may need a new filter as well - if there was a lot of crud in the tank the new filter could be clogged.

If you have a power vent rather than a traditional chimney, the possible causes of abnormal shutdown increase.